# Windows can access the phone's internal storage over USB, but not it's Micro sD card

Tags: usb, external-sd, windows, 9.0-pie

My Samsung Galaxy A8+ (A730F), running Android Pie, had a faulty USB connector due to water damage and for a very long time, it wouldn't connect over USB. Nevertheless, everything else worked just fine.

Recently I had this piece replaced by a technician and it seems to be working alright, but I just noticed that on Windows, my 128GB micro SD card is shown next to my Internal Storage as empty and with a size of 128MB.

I can interact normally with the Internal Storage and when I put the micro SD card in a card adapter and plug it on my PC, everything works fine.

I'm using and original USB cable, my micro SD card is legitimate (confirmed it on SanDisk's website) and there aren't any other issues. Also, I have root access.

I tried clearing cache/data on Media Storage and External Storage, but had no luck.

I know that if nothing helps, I'll have to contact the technician, but I'd like to discard other possibilities first.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: Try different ports on laptop /USB cables to see if that helps?

Comment: Did it, the problem is still there :/

Comment: Which file-system is used by the external micro-sd card? Have you performed a file-system check if the file-system itself has problems?

Comment: I happened to have another phone of the exact same model and another micro SD card for testing. Every combination of ports, cables and cards worked with the other phone, but did not with mine, so the problem is definitely on my phone!